# how to pass a reference variable in realm.object().filtered()

Tags: react-native, realm

I want to search database using realm api , I dont find any way to pass variable

```
 let filterOpenRecord =  realm.objects('RepleteMedicalCondition').filtered('codeDescription = "`${this.state.MCDescription}`" AND closed = false');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
 let filterOpenRecord =  realm.objects('RepleteMedicalCondition').filtered('codeDescription = $0 AND closed = false', this.state.MCDescription);
```

Comment: throws Error :codeDescription = $desc AND closed = false:1:19: Invalid predicate. – abdul just now   edit

Comment: Could you paste here what did you try?

Comment: let desc = this.state.MCDescription
    let filterOpenRecord =  realm.objects('RepleteMedicalCondition').filtered('codeDescription = $desc AND closed = false');

Comment: This is not what i suggested. Try
let desc = this.state.MCDescription;
let filterOpenRecord = realm.objects('RepleteMedicalCondition').filtered('codeDescr‌​iption = $0 AND closed = false', desc);

Comment: this worked:   let desc = this.state.MCDescription
    let filterOpenRecord =  realm.objects('RepleteMedicalCondition').filtered(`codeDescription = "${desc}" AND closed = false`);